# How to determine which MCU pins support hardware PWM from datasheet?

Tags: microcontroller, datasheet

Most of the time i'm used to finding a pin-out with a "squiggly" mark next to the pins or some other indication. But in this usb controller there are quite a lot of GPIO pins (almost 60), yet no mention anywhere in the document of PWM capability. If pwm is not explicitly mentioned in the datasheet, how safe is it to assume that it's not a supported feature of the device? There are also GPIF II pins which i'm not quite familiar with.

Link: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-CYUSB301X_CYUSB201X_EZ-USB_FX3_SUPERSPEED_USB_CONTROLLER-DataSheet-v21_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7d0d8da4017d0eca1e7442aa

Comment: PWM might also be called an output compare module. If it doesn't have it then it doesn't have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to the [Reference Manual](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-EZ-USB_FX3_Technical_Reference_Manual-AdditionalTechnicalInformation-v07_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7d0d8da4017d0f90b94c7db6), it states in Section 4 "Global Controller (GCTL)":

> There are eight complex I/O pin groups, the elements of which are chosen in a modulo 8 fashion (complex I/O group 0: GPIO 0, 8, 16; complex I/O group 1: GPIO 1, 9, 17, and so on). Each group can have different complex I/O functions (such as **PWM**, one shot, and so on). However, only one pin from a group can use the complex I/O functions.

To me this seems to imply that the device could potentially produce up to 8 PWM signals (one from each "complex I/O pin group"), and that you can choose which pin in each pin group will be used to output the PWM signal.

<sub>I have never used this device or any others in the family - this is just my interpretation of what I see in the Ref Manual.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

A microcontroller that has a built-in PWM peripheral requires, at minimum, a counter with a clock input, registers to set the frequency and the duty cycle, and compare units to determine when the counter register's contents are equal.

The venerable [ATMega328P](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf) (which you may be familiar with from the Arduino Uno), for example, has three on-chip timers (sections 14, 15, and 16 in the datasheet). The programmer can select a clock source and a clock prescaling factor (which divides the input clock), and then write an 8-bit (timers 0 and 2) or 16-bit (timer 1) value into the compare registers. The timers can be used to trigger interrupts, or for PWM mode, will toggle the output pin.

Note that the actual operation of a PWM peripherial is quite complicated. In the example above, over 40 pages are devoted to its operation! If your datasheet does not describe any of this functionality, you can safely conclude that the chip does not support PWM. If you need to use this chip, you'll either need a separate device to generate PWM signals, or you'll have to explicitly drive the signal by turning its GPIO on and off directly.